# Providing multiple arguments to an anonymous function in setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm not sure if this Javascript question has been asked before- I couldn't find it, but if I've missed it, my apologies.

I'm trying to create a page with checkboxes that will fade in/out a corresponding image. The fading will take 1 second, every 100ms, the opacity of the image increases or decreases by 0.1; when the opacity reaches 0 or 1, the setInterval call is stopped. However, I'm not sure how to pass arguments to an anonymous function call. I'm trying to pass two variables - the first is the ID of the image, obtained from the checkbox value, and the other is whether the tickbox is checked or not, so that the function knows whether to fade in or out.

However, I have run into a problem with the code as is (see below) and I think its due to the scope of the variables within the setInterval function call - thats why I'm asking about passing multiple arguments into the call.

for example:

```
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" onclick='handleClick(this);' name="skymap" value="aurora">Aurora
<input type="checkbox" onclick='handleClick(this);' name="skymap" value="mainindex">Main Index
</form>
```

And the function is as follows (so far)

```
function handleClick(cb) 
{

var myInterval = setInterval(function () 
{
  if (cb.checked) // tick box checked - fade in.
  {
    document.getElementById( cb.value ).style.opacity+=0.1;  // I'll refactor all these style.opacity calls later on :)

    if( document.getElementById( cb.value ).style.opacity>1 ) // full opacity - stop the timer
    {
        document.getElementById( cb.value ).style.opacity = 1;
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
}
else // fade out
{
    document.getElementById( cb.val ).style.opacity-=0.1;

    if( document.getElementById( cb.val ).style.opacity<0 )
    {
        document.getElementById( cb.val ).style.opacity = 0;
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
}


}, 100);


}
```

The images are called things like:

```
<img id="aurora" src="aurora.png" />
```

Comment: I don't see any params getting passed in right now?

Comment: That's the problem - I'm not sure how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into a tricky problem there.

First, you have written "cb.val" instead of "cb.value" in the else section

Second, the opacity property of the object "cb" is of type string. The -= operation converts the opacity value into a number, as you cant do a minus operation on a string. The += operation instead, converts the number (0.1) into a string and adds to the end of the opacity string (e.g. if opacity is 0.1, the result will be "0.10.1"). As this value is invalid, it will be set to the last valid value and you are stuck in the loop

Here is a working example:

```
function handleClick(cb) 
{

var myInterval = setInterval(function () 
{
  if (cb.checked) // tick box checked - fade in.
  {
    document.getElementById( cb.value ).style.opacity = parseFloat(document.getElementById( cb.value ).style.opacity) + 0.1  // I'll refactor all these style.opacity calls later on :)

    if( document.getElementById( cb.value ).style.opacity>1 ) // full opacity - stop the timer
    {
        document.getElementById( cb.value ).style.opacity = 1;
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
}
else // fade out
{
    document.getElementById( cb.value ).style.opacity-=0.1;

    if( document.getElementById( cb.value ).style.opacity<0 )
    {
        document.getElementById( cb.value ).style.opacity = 0;
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
}


}, 100);


}
```

Another problem you could run into is, that the opacity property is not set by default (or at least you cant be sure). So the first time, opacity = "", empty string. This will cause jumps in your animation. Be sure to initialize the opacity if you detect an empty string.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need! The cb.val and the lack of initial opacity was just due to my sloppy copying and pasting, but it works perfectly, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the optional parameters of the `setInterval(function(arg1, arg2, ..){...}, intervalTime, arg1, arg2,...)` function

```
function handleClick(cb) 
{

    var myInterval = setInterval(function (checked, imgId) 
        {
          if (checked) // tick box checked - fade in.
          {
            document.getElementById( imgId ).style.opacity+=0.1;  // I'll refactor all these style.opacity calls later on :)

            if( document.getElementById( imgId ).style.opacity>1 ) // full opacity - stop the timer
            {
                document.getElementById( imgId ).style.opacity = 1;
                clearInterval(myInterval);
            }
        }
        else // fade out
        {
            document.getElementById( imgId ).style.opacity-=0.1;

            if( document.getElementById( imgId ).style.opacity<0 )
            {
                document.getElementById( imgId ).style.opacity = 0;
                clearInterval(myInterval);
            }
        }
        }, 100, cb.checked, cb.value);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use cb.checked in your existing code, but to answer your question as asked: with setInterval and setTimeout, you just use the closure functionality to pass variables in, because values from the outer scope (function) at the time of evaluation are available to you. At a very simple level you can do something like:

```
function myTimeoutClosure(greeting, subject) {
    return function() {
        console.log(greeting + " " + subject);
    };
}
// ...
setTimeout(myTimeoutClosure("Hello", "World"), 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of it, the way you were headed was going to potentially have some issues with people repeatedly clicking on the checkboxes, and stacking up a bunch of intervals on top of each other. In this case, you have a function that calls itself with a timeout and steps through the transition, rather than relying on an interval outright.

```js
function fadeElement(elem, increment) {

  elem.style.opacity = parseFloat(elem.style.opacity) + increment;

  if (elem.style.opacity >= 1) {
    elem.style.opacity = 1
  } else if (elem.style.opacity <= 0) {
    elem.style.opacity = 0
  } else {
    clearTimeout(elem.getAttribute('data-timeout'))
    elem.setAttribute('data-timeout', setTimeout(function() {
      fadeElement(elem, increment)
    }, 100))
  }
}

function handleClick(cb) {

  var chkbox = document.getElementById(cb.value);
  var direction = cb.checked ? 0.1 : -0.1;

  fadeElement(chkbox, direction)


}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="checkbox" checked onclick='handleClick(this);' name="skymap" value="aurora">Aurora
  <input type="checkbox" checked onclick='handleClick(this);' name="skymap" value="mainindex">Main Index
</form>
<p id="aurora" style="opacity:1">Aurora</p>
<p id="mainindex" style="opacity:1">Main Index</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an example. I hope this is what your are looking for. Just let me know.

```
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" class='imageSelect' name="skymap" value="aurora">Aurora
<input type="checkbox"  class= 'imageSelect' name="skymap" value="mainindex">Main Index
</form>
<div id="aurora" style="background:yellow; width:150px; height:40px; float:left; display:none;">Aurora Image </div>
<div id="mainindex" style="background:blue; width:150px; height:40px;float:left; display:none;">MainIndex Image </div>
```

The JS:

```
function CheckBoxClick(){
    $(".imageSelect").click(function(){
        /*if(this.checked){
             $("#"+$(this).val()+" ").fadeIn();
          }else{
             $("#"+$(this).val()+" ").fadeOut();
          }*/
     $("#"+$(this).val()+" ").toggle(this.checked)
    });
};
```

The fade efect looks better but it's your call if you use it or not, both work. Here the code to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/dzgppqap/

PD: Remember add the event when the page is ready:

```
$(document).ready(CheckBoxClick());
```